# Vue.js: How can I update a single item in a "list" - computed property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to determine the best pattern to solve the following:

- I want to show a list of people in a specific department
- I made the department index a regular, reactive Vue property
- I made the list of people in the department a computed property

Now:

- My backend (a Mac app) can dispatch a "Person at index changed" event and I must reload the name of a single person.
- But: the person property is an item in a computed property (i.e. "people", see code below).

How can I update the name of a person in the list list of people, which in turn is a computed property (although it is "computed" from the `departmentIndex` + backend call)?

I assume that I have a mistake in my original setup. Maybe the people list should not be a computed property in the first place?

Here is the code:

```
function pretendUpdateEventFromBackend() {
   var event = new CustomEvent('PersonUpdated', {detail:{index:1, name:'Jimmy'}});

  document.dispatchEvent(event);
}

var backend = {
  // The actual backend is a Mac app with an embedded WebView...
  listPeopleInDepartment(departmentIndex) {
    return [
      {name:'John'},
      {name:'James'},
      {name:'Jane'}
    ];
  }
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
      message:'',
      departmentIndex:0,
  },

   computed: {

    people() {
      return backend.listPeopleInDepartment(this.departmentIndex);
    }
  },

  created() {
    const me = this;
    document.addEventListener('PersonUpdated', function(e){

      me.message += 'Updated ';

      var personIndex = e.detail.index;
      var newName = e.detail.name;

      // How can I update person in the list of computed people here?
      // Or how can I force a reload of the people list?

      me.message += 'Person at: ' + personIndex + ' new name: ' + newName + "\n";  
    });
  },
});
```

Html:

```
      <button onclick="pretendUpdateEventFromBackend()">Trigger Update Event from Backend</button>

      <div id="app">

        <div class="person" v-for="person in people">
          Name: {{ person.name }}
        </div>

        <pre>{{message}}</pre>

      </div>
```

**EDIT:**

Try it on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/guwezoyena/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Instead of broadcasting the index of changed person, why can't you provide an Id for each person and broadcast it instead? Then you can find the person in the original backing list and change it there.

Comment: Your example looks very complicated for what you're asking. Is there a reason for that? Did you simplified some part that should work this way? I mean your `pretendUpdateEventFromBackend()` call on button click is not even in your `Vue`. You're using `new CustomEvent()` , maybe you should stick to `vm.$emit()` instead.

Comment: @MathewJibin: The "backend" in my example is actually an AJAX call to the server. The custom event already comes with the index of the person to update in the `detail` object so I know what to update, just how I do this is not clear to me.

Comment: @Elfayer: `pretendUpdateEventFromBackend` is just a mock to show that from somewhere outside of the Vue app, a change event can be issued and is not under control of my Vue client code.

Comment: The computed property will be using a list of items anyway right? find the item in that list and update it there, Make the computed property return references instead of creating new objects. The updating underlying item property will automatically updates the bindings.

Comment: @MathewJibin: So `me.people[personIndex].name = newName;` just works? Indeed it does... I was not aware that I actually can change a computed property. I guess the "computed" part is only the "list", not the actual items in the list?

Comment: @MathewJibin It turns out your answer is the solution to my question above. My actual problem lies somewhere else: In my code I use custom components and bind a component property to the value I update from the backend. This in turn is used in another computed property and this change is not propagated down to the component. Feel free to add your answer here and I'll accept it so that you get the credit. Thanks to the both of your for your quick help!

Comment: Actually, this is not solved. Running this code does not update the UI: `window.app.people[0].name = Date()`  jsbin: http://jsbin.com/rinotixufi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Your example doesn't show from where the computed property get its value. This is important, if you are trying to issue ajax call in computed property, I have bad news for you.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion with the AXAJ backend. I wanted to keep things simple. My actual backend is a Mac app. The Vue.js app runs in an embedded WebView in a standalone app so no AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought I should give you some further insight on your setup:

If `listPeopleInDepartment` is an ajax call in your actual code, this might be a bad pattern. See, Vue will identify every property (including other computed properties) that is used within a computed property and make it sure to re-compute it whenever any of them changes. In your case, this would mean whenever `departmentIndex` changes it'll recompute `people`.

Here's why it *might* be problematic, since you must return the result of the ajax request, it can't be asynchronous so it'll be a blocking call that would render the page unresponsive while it runs. Also, let's say you were viewing department 1, then you change to 2, if you go back to 1 it'll have to reload the people in department 1 because it's not stored anywhere.

You should probably implement some caching strategy and have ajax loads only when that data isn't already available, also in a non blocking fashion. You could achieve this with an array that stores the arrays of peopleInDepartment indexed by department id, and a watcher for `departmentIndex` that would do something like this:

```
function (newValue){
    if (!this.peopleCache[newValue]){
        var that = this;
        //Load it via ajax
        loadPeopleInDepartment(newValue, function(result){
            that.peopleCache[newValue] = result;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! My app actually runs as a Mac app in an embedded WebView, so the AJAX call is actually a call into the hosting app. No need to add caching at this point. I updated the question to reflect this. Yes, whenever the department index changes, the list of people must update (there are prev/next buttons to browse departments).